# identify date format 09-08-2014

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have more than 5000 records in a mysql DB  where the date is stored in `varchar` format.

Example dates & format

```
09-08-2014 dd-mm-yy 
4-2-2014 mm-dd-yy
2014-4-4 yy-mm-dd
```

How can I identify each date format and change it to a common format?

The problem I am facing is that when I run a query to fetch dd-mm-yy,  I get the same values for mm-dd-yy as well.

Comment: no rule means no algorithm.

Comment: You are bolluxed mixing dd-mm and mm-dd is a total no-no

Comment: Your date is ambiguous.  It could be either September 8th or August 9th.  There is no way to disambiguate it out of context.

Comment: If you know where the data came from (locale, I mean), you might be able to GUESS. If the locale was U.S., I'd GUESS it to be mm-dd-yy and europe GUESS it to be dd-mm-yy.

Comment: There is no way you can say `4-2-2014` is the fourth of february 2014 or the second of april 2014 if you have no well defined format for every row

Comment: it is impossible to fix this if you have not stored the format, how can you say a date `10-05-2014` is 10th of May 2014 or `5th Oct 2014`

Comment: Is there any way you can say that "this row use this date format because it has this particularity" (based on another field i.e.) ?

Comment: Is there another field in the database which defines the format? without it I'm with everyone else, you really can't.

Comment: actually 4-2-2014 is mm-dd-yy and 04-02-2014 is dd-mm-yy -----u wont get the zero's for mm-dd-yy. i just want it like a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys

i solved the problem through a REGEX since its in varchar format.Had to generate regex for all the available format

used this regex to filter dd/mm/yy -REGEXP '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}';

Reference
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/

Answer (score 0):

No rule means No algorithm.

What you ask sound like a one time work, in the way to have reasonable data.

When you reach dates stored as varchars, many things may be wrong. The ones that you mention and some other worst, like not a date at all like `60/90/2014`

But, a general rule on a column is that its content is uniform, so you can investigate with some querys if you have strings in the form of `xx-yy-AAAA` where `xx` is greater than 12 or `yy` is greater than 12 and **assume** that all the column share the same format.

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach, **but it is ambiguous** for mm-dd-yy and dd-mm-yy date formats with dd and mm values less or equal to 12.

Creating table and insert sample values:

```
create table dates(
    stored_date varchar(20)
);


insert into dates (stored_date)
values 
('09-08-2014'),
('4-2-2014'),
('2014-4-4');
```

Query to extract date value for each row:

```
select stored_date,  
case 
  when date(stored_date) = stored_date then
    date(stored_date)
  when str_to_date(stored_date,'%d-%m-%Y') is not null then
    str_to_date(stored_date,'%d-%m-%Y')
  when str_to_date(stored_date,'%m-%d-%Y') is not null then
    str_to_date(stored_date,'%m-%d-%Y')
 else 
    null
 end as parsed_date
from dates;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| stored_date | parsed_date |
+-------------+-------------+
| 09-08-2014  | 2014-08-09  |
| 4-2-2014    | 2014-02-04  |
| 2014-4-4    | 2014-04-04  |
+-------------+-------------+
```

You will need to filter the date format manually but maybe it will be some rows (not the 5000 records)